# E-R entity design for a web application

Tags: database, entity-relationship

for exercise, I have to design a web application with online forums. Each forum refers to a specific category of sport and a specific course, e.g. soccer forum of informatic. Each user can submit a post in a forum, this post has a text, a photo and a date.
I've designed the forum like an entity with only one attribute, the category (of sport), and the post like another entity, linked by a "part of" relationship with Forum.
The Forum is linked by a relationship with the entity Course.
Do you think this is the best solution?
Thanks.
Here's an image of my elaboration:
[image: model]

Comment: Can you post an image of your work? It's better than explain it with words

Comment: I've just edited my message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Each user can submit a post in a forum, this post has a text, a photo and a date.

So I would add the entity "user" which would have a relation with post (users submits posts) and then I would put a relation between "user" and "forum" because the user that is subscribed to the forum writes posts. Because of this, I would cancel the relation between "forum" and "post". In addtion a forum belongs only to a course I think. However consider that this is my own solution and an E/R model can be done in many ways.
This is my solution:

[image]

Comment: Well, I've posted only a part of my model (it's in another language), obviously there is the entity User and is related with the post. In my specifications there is no mention of a "subscription", it is only written that an user can submit a post in a tematic forum. So, there is no "direct" connection among the user and the forum, except for the fact that an user inserts a post in a specific forum. But maybe you're right...as I've done this fact it's not clear...thanks

Comment: I have a doubt: from your model it's not clear on what forum is posted the message; am I wrong?

Comment: The relationship between Forum and User is N:M so "subscribed to" would become a table containing 2 foreign key, one for the Forum and one for the User.  Using this method you can see through the user which post is related to which forum. For example if you write a query to search the forum in which a post is contained, you would write "SELECT Id FROM Posts, Users, Forums WHERE link_iduser = Username and link_subsuser = Username AND link_forum = category AND Category = Something;" where link_subsuser and link_forum are contained in table Subscription as foreign keys

Comment: I miswrote the type of the relation between POST and USER: it's (1;1) because a post is written only by a user and so POST would contain a foreign key to USER (link_iduser)

Comment: Why the relation between USER and FORUM is (1;N)? An user could not have a subscription to a forum, and a FORUM could have 0 users, certainly it's like that at the moment of the creation of a forum. I guess. Thanks.

Comment: It's better to manage data avoiding waste of space. If a user is not subscripted to any forum, the user isn't contained in the database. Also is very unlikely to have a forum with no users

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148551/discussion-between-jamieitgirl-and-gymni-f).